# When were dugout railings added in MLB?

Tags: baseball, trivia, history, mlb

I was watching the movie "Major League" with my wife when she asked about the absence of the dugout railings. She assumed it was for the movie.

I explained that they were added fairly recently (early 90s perhaps) but can't find anything to confirm this.

When were dugout railings first used in the MLB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [blog](https://angelswinblog.blogspot.com/2012/01/where-are-they-now-mo-vaughn.html) about the Angels suggests that fences were added to dugouts shortly after Mo Vaughn's 1999 injury.

> It should be noted that after Vaughn’s opening day tumble, many
>   stadiums around Major League Baseball put fences in front of their
>   dugouts to avoid any future injuries of this nature.

This [Chicago Tribune](http://articles.chicagotribune.com/2002-05-12/sports/0205120214_1_major-league-baseball-major-league-dugouts) article mentions that the process was underway, but not complete league-wide in 2002.

> Some teams have put up fences or netting in front of dugouts to
>   protect their players...